# How to access data from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The thing is I am making a product web app in which I have included a features of product which I want to access and print it on the web.
Basically I am using React to make the project.

Here is my code which conatins array:

```
const products = [
    {
        _id: '1',
        name: 'Kalonji Oil',
        image: '/images/kalonji.jpg',
        description:'Kalonjitel or The COLD PRESSED Black Cumin Seed Oil extracted 100% pure and is unfiltered with no added preservatives.',
        feat:[
            {
                feat1: 'ABC',
                feat2: 'CZX',
                feat3: 'jkl',
                feat4: 'kdh',
                feat5: 'iuo',
                feat6: 'yth',
                feat7: 'rty',
                feat8: 'ghj'
            },
        ],  
        brand:'EWFSA',
        category:'Foods',
        price:70,
        countInStock:5,
        rating: 4,
        numReviews: 4,
    },
    {
        _id: '2',
        name: 'Coconut oil',
        image: '/images/coconut.jpg',
        description:'Nariyaltel or The COLD PRESSED Coconut Oil has numerous health benefits.',
        feat:[
            {
                feat1: 'ABC',
                feat2: 'CZX',
                feat3: 'jkl',
                feat4: 'kdh',
                feat5: 'iuo',
                feat6: 'yth',
                feat7: 'rty',
                feat8: 'ghj'
            },
        ],
        brand:'EWFSA',
        category:'Foods',
        price: 70,
        countInStock:5,
        rating:4.5,
        numReviews: 4,
    },
}

export default products
```

And I want to access feat object from the above array but I dont know how.

I tried this:

```
<ListGroup.Item>
                {product.map(function(products)
                {
                    <ul>
                        <li>{product.feat}</li>
                    </ul>
                })}
 </ListGroup.Item>
```

But its not working

```
<ListGroup.Item>
            {products.map((product, index) => (
        <ul key={index}>
          {Object.values(product.feat[0]).map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ))}
            </ListGroup.Item>
```

[The output which I got is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAVMw.png)

[And what I want is this, the only list with black border i.e. the feat. list of that particular product and not feat list of all the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tawpp.png)

Comment: you're not returning anything inside the callback passed to map

Comment: `product.feat` is an array so you'll need a nested map

Comment: your array is called `products` , but you call map on `product`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is your map isn't doing it correctly; it needs to return a value to be rendered. Second, the `feat` key is an array of objects whose values you want printed and thus needs to be looped through also. You need something like this:

```
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <Row key={index} className="p-4 border-bottom">
          <Col>
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/watch-icon-260nw-257354227.jpg" />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <div>Descriptoion: {product.description}</div>
            <div>
              <ListGroup key={index} className="mb-2">
                {Object.values(product.feat[0]).map((item, i) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={i}>{item}</ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      ))}
```

Note the `Object.values(product.feat[0])` part. That's because the `feat` key is an array that contains one object in your case.

The code is just to give you a general idea of how to render your data. Here is a Sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cartwright-dkns9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I got you but the now the all the product features are comming on every individual products i.e. when showing one product features (feat) , all other features are also showing up. The feat list is going till the length of the product.

Comment: @AbhijeetKujur Why don't you update your question with what your exact desired outcome should look like and we will take it from there.

Comment: @AbhijeetKujur The Sanbox will now give you what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/dkns9

Answer (score 0):

**There are two issues here:**

1- Products object has an error in his construction. You are creating an array but you are ending the object with a **curly brace** instead of a **square bracket**.

2- The map function is fine but you are trying to use "**feat**" that is an array. Try to use "**name**" instead and would work.

**If you want to list the content of "feat" you should map it into an array as other comments explain.**a

**18/01/2020 Update base on post Update:**

If you want to show up just a specific product content you must find by **_id** value.

Taking into account that you already have the ***_id*** value you would like to show up in your component, try this:

```
export default function App() {    
  const yourProductId = '1';
  const product = products.find(p=> p._id === yourProductId);
  return (
    <div className="App">      
          <ul>        
          {Object.values(product.feat[0]).map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul> 
    </div>
  );
}
```